# Reinstalled MySQL on ubuntu 12.04 server now websites wont load?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, reinstall

Had an issue with mysql on the server so decided to completely remove it via the following

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
rm -rf /etc/mysql*
```

then the following to reinstall

```
apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

After adding my the relevant DBs, tables & content I would have thought the websites would have resumed as normal. As it stands the page doesn't load but doesn't give any error message which made me think it might be messing with apache in some fashion.

But checking the apache error log doesn't show any errors, any ideas?

UPDATE

It appears i need to reinstall mysqli, just need to remember how I done it last time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using PHP? If so turn on [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Is the webapp accessing the DB from a remote location or on the same server?

Comment: Think i've found the cause *PHP Fatal error:  Class 'mysqli' not found in ....*

Comment: There you go. You need to `apt-get install php-mysql` or something similar, probably.

Comment: Spot on, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You really haven't given us much information to go on.  I would follow the basic troubleshooting steps.

1. Make sure mysql is running
2. Log into mysql with the username/password that the website would
3. Check to ensure tables are created
4. Look at applications connection string to see if you are connecting to a file or a port